# Landau–Lifshitz–Gilbert equation without damping : name and solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying the following equation

$$\frac{d\mathbf{M}}{dt}=\mathbf{B} (t) \times \mathbf{M}(t) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{d}{dt} \left(\begin{array}{c}
M_x\\
M_y\\
M_z
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
B_y M_z-B_z M_y \\
B_z M_x-B_x M_z \\
B_x M_y-B_y M_x
\end{array}\right)$$

which is known in physics as the [Landau–Lifshitz–Gilbert equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation) without damping.

I would like to know if this equation (which describes the precession of the magnetisation $M$ around the vector $B$) has a name in mathematics, and if its solutions are known in the general case for a smooth vector $B(t)$ and for dimension $3$ (as I write them in components).

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be written in 'matrix form' as
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} \mathbf{x}}{\text{d} t} = \mathbf{A}(t)\,\mathbf{x}, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{A}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -B_z & B_y \\ B_z & 0 & -B_x \\ -B_y & B_x & 0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
For *general* smooth $B(t)$, equation $(1)$ is the general form of a nonautonomous linear (three-dimensional) system, with the only additional constraint that the matrix $\mathbf{A}(t)$ is antisymmetric, i.e. $\mathbf{A}^T = - \mathbf{A}$. Because this setting is so general, there are no explicit results for general $\mathbf{B}(t)$. If $\mathbf{B}(t)$ is periodic in time, however, it's worth looking into [Floquet theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory).

Regarding the name, as far as I know this equation is only known as the Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert equation. There are some interesting results on the solutions of this equation when $\mathbf{B}$ is a function of $\mathbf{M}$, yielding a nonlinear but autonomous system of ODE's, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5523).